# Why does IDEA not resolve scala.reflect, but scala-reflect is included in project settings?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am working with the latest IntelliJ 14 edition with all the latest plugins.  Also, I am on Mac Yosemite.

I am trying to simply import scala reflect so I can work with `TypeTag`

When I try to do this...

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
```

IntelliJ is complaining that it doesn't know what that is.  When I try to go through code assist, it also cannot see a `runtime` package inside of `scala.reflect`

I see the scala-reflect library in the project settings.  I also tried adding by hand the scala-reflect as a `libraryDependency` of the project.  Nothing seems to be working.

Anyone else hit this issue?

Comment: Do you have something like `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value` in your `build.sbt` file? Did you refresh the project after importing it, or modifying `build.sbt`?

Comment: Adding the library apparently solved for me. I also ran sbt form the command-line, not sure if I had reloaded from within IntelliJ already.

Comment: I faced the same issue, adding `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value` in built.sbt solved the IDE warning, but it was working fine in Scala REPL by just importing `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`

Answer (score 7):

Go to your project structure and check the dependency of you module. Make sure that org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:VERSION:jar has scope set to compile.